# My Python script is accepting integers but not strings why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
for i in range(5):
    value = input ("Enter the value : ")
    print value
```

**While string as input:**

```
$ ./fun+for.py 
Enter the value : John
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fun+for.py", line 13, in <module>
    value = input ("Enter the value : ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'John' is not defined
```

**While integer input:**

```
$ ./fun+for.py 
Enter the value : 4
4
Enter the value : 5
5
Enter the value : 6
6
Enter the value : 7
7
Enter the value : 7
7
```

Comment: I know it's in python2.7, but the issue is not with printing, it is with assigning a string to  "value", The string entered in quotes are accepted. But i want to input strings without quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Because in Python2, the string you enter really goes through an eval(), so it searches `John` as a variable name (try entering `2+1`). Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` (in python3, `input()` no longer does this).

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score -2):

This is because it is python 2; it will work if you copy and paste this code in python 3 -- it's better, I think. you will be able to input strings, integers, and doubles without receiving an error.

```
for i in range(5):
    value = input ("Enter the value : ")
    print (value)
```

- You **need parenthesis**  when you print value for python3.

..hope this helps.

Comment: This does not explain that `raw_input` should be used instead.

Comment: @Gamer1337
 your comment is also correct in case of python3.5